# Windows 10 IoT Enterprise - Soft Real-time Performance with Audio Service enabled

Tags: windows-10-iot-enterprise

I want to use soft real-time performance on Windows 10 IoT Enterprise, but in the required steps it lists disabling the Windows Audio Service. Is there any way to keep audio on the machine while still utilizing RTP? This feature is exclusive to this version of Windows and is a drawing point for [Kiosk Mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/iot-enterprise/kiosk-mode/kiosk-mode), but it removes any and all audio from your device. That doesn't seem like a fair trade...

One thought I had was dedicating a core(s) to the service because perhaps the issue was that the service was being pervasive to the CPU cores regardless of RTP which in turn affects RTP, but this was really just a shot in the dark since there is zero explanation as to why any of the services are required to be disabled in the first place. Regardless, it was not possible to even attempt this because Windows does not allow changing core affinity for Windows processes (from what little I have seen online on this subject).